# Push local repo to new sub-directory of remote repo

Tags: git

I have a local git repository that I created and have been using for months. However this work will now be part of a larger project that has an existing repository, so I'd like to add the larger project's server as a remote and push my work into a sub-directory of that repository.

However I believe these naive steps will push my local repo into the top-level directory of the larger project's repo:

```
$ pwd
/home/yotommy/my-local-project
$ git remote add origin git://example.com/gitscn/larger-project.git
$ git push origin master ### goes to top-level directory, not desired!
```

I tried specifying a (not-yet-existing) subdirectory:

```
$ git remote add origin git://example.com/gitscm/larger-project.git/my/sub/dir
$ git push origin master
fatal: '/gitscm/larger-project.git/my/sub/dir' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Should I add the sub-directory to the larger-project repo first? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Checkout git-submodule. What you want to do, as is, is not possible (and make no sense in a version control logic).

Comment: Thanks, I will check out git-submodule. My goal is to integrate my code and all of its history into the larger project's repository. Is it the goal that makes no sense, or my approach to the goal?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Actually, what he wants is entirely possible (I've done it several times), but it's not simple or intuitive, and there's at least two different main methods for it - one using `git subtree`, and one using `git merge -s subtree`, both of which are pretty simple google finds - and [one](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/merge-two-git-repositories-into-one/) low-level one using `git read-tree` and other plumbing commands.

Comment: Ah, maybe I haven't understood correctly. @yotommy, after the merge, you do not wish to keep working inside your repo, you'll always work from the larger-project?

Comment: Correct, @SimonBoudrias, I think of it as moving from my local repo to a subdir of larger-project.

Comment: @twalberg, these are great leads. Investigating now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the lead from @twalberg, I found [documentation for subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging). Here is a condensed recipe for the case posed in the question.

```
$ git clone git://example.com/gitscm/larger-project.git
$ git remote add subproj_remote /home/yotommy/my-local-project
$ git fetch subproj_remote
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 461, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (332/332), done.
remote: Total 461 (delta 157), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (461/461), 272.89 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (157/157), done.
From subproj_remote /home/yotommy/my-local-project
 * [new branch]      master     -> subproj_remote/master
$ git checkout -b subproj_branch subproj_remote/master
Branch subproj_branch set up to track remote branch master from subproj_remote.
Switched to a new branch 'subproj_branch'
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git read-tree --prefix=subproj/ -u subproj_branch
$ git commit -m "merged subproj"
```

Comment: i am slightly confused. How do I push updates to the larger project branch in a situation where subproject gets new commits?

Comment: nm.. found the answer in the link you provided: `git merge -s subtree <local branch that tracks the "real" folder>`

Comment: I found that `git merge -s subtree <local_branch> --allow-unrelated-histories` does the trick if git complains about unrelated histories.